# Create simple calculator with Dynamic AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++

I'm new with Dynamic AX and I want to create a simple calculator with input values and display the result in the form:

[image]

Comment: To learn more about forms take a look on forms named "Tutorial_" fx. `Tutorial_Form_Controls`.

You need to expand your question with what you have tried and what did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad to be answered precisely because there are a lot of strategies to tackle the task, but judging from the screenshot you have provided you have a class which should contain all calculation logic and a form to provide UI to the user with two input fields and one output field which should display operation result.

So the easiest solution would be:

1. Implement the `Kalkulator` class which exposes two `parm` methods to
   set up the operands and four methods which execute the
   operation and return the result: `add`, `subtract`, `multiply` and `divide`.
2. Create a private instance of the `Kalkulator` class in your form,
   initialize it, set up operands when user clicks one of the buttons,
   call appropriate method to run the operation and output the result
   on the form field.

So supposing that operands are integer values (for demonstrative purpose) your `TRN_Kalkulator` may look something like this:

```
class TRN_Kalkulator
{
    private int value1;
    private int value2;

    public int parmValue1(int _value = value1)
    {
        value1 = _value;
        return value1;
    }

    public int parmValue2(int _value = value2)
    {
        value2 = _value;
        return value2;
    }

    public int Sum()
    {
        return value1 + value2;
    }

    public int Diff()
    {
        return value1 - value2;
    }

    public int Mult()
    {
        return value1 * value2;
    }

    public int Div()
    {
        return value2 == 0 ? 0 : value1 / value2;
    }

}
```

In the class declaration on the form you have to declare a private instance of `TRN_Kalkulator` which will be initialized by overriding the `init()` method:

```
TRN_Kalkulator calculator;
//...
public void init()
{
    super();
    calculator = new TRN_Kalkulator();
}
```

Finally when one of the buttons is clicked you parse user input by reading the values of the form fields, set up the operands, run the operation and output the result. All of this is done by overriding `click()` method on each of the buttons:

```
// read text values of the textboxes and parse them to integer
int a = str2Int(TxtOperand1.text());
int b = str2Int(TxtOperand2.text());

// set up calculator operands
calculator.parmValue1(a);
calculator.parmValue2(b);

// call the operation depending on which button was clicked
int result = calculator.Sum();

// set result textbox text
TxtResult.text(int2Str(result));
```

Notice that there are a lot of ways to improve this code (like for example using some [display](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Display_method) and [edit](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Edit_method) methods on the form) and you definitely should do it, but this implementation suits your current setup and should point you in the right direction.

Comment: thank u so much, actualy i have create first point but i can execute that, your answer is very helpfull

Comment: Of cause, if your two controls are `FormRealControl` you can use the `operand1.realValue()` to get the values directly.